# Align all h3's on the same line and change color on hover?

Tags: html, css

How can I simply align all 3 of these H3's on the same line, with a black background behind each that turns gray on hover (rectangle behind each)?
Thanks

CSS:

```
        #NavBar {
            text-align:center;
            vertical-align:middle;
        }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="Navbar">
                <h3 id="Tab-1" class="Active">Home</h3>
                <h3 id="Tab-2" class="Inactive">Alpha Keys</h3>
                <h3 id="Tab-3" class="Inactive">About</h3>
            </div>
```

Comment: h3 { display: inline-block; background: #000; }
h3:hover { background: #333 !important; }

Comment: Really you don't know how to add a background color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All heading tags H1,H2,H3,H4 are block level elements. this is the reason they take full width. So if you need to turn any block level element into inline element so they can next to each other. you can use `display:inline` or you want them same they treated as `block` and `inline` element use `display:inline-block`.

In your case like I said those tag are block level element so you can use `display:inline-block` to align them next to each other..

```
#Navbar{color:#fff;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;}
#Navbar h3{display:inline-block; background:#000; padding:5px;margin:5px;}
#Navbar h3:hover{display:inline-block; background:#333; cursor:pointer;}
#Navbar h3.Active{background:#333; text-decoration:underline;}
```

and here is the HTML structure.

```
<div id="Navbar">
<h3 id="Tab-1" class="Active">Home</h3>
<h3 id="Tab-2" class="Inactive">Alpha Keys</h3>
<h3 id="Tab-3" class="Inactive">About</h3>
</div>
```

Here is the ***[Demo](http://jsbin.com/wiyihuku/1/)***.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your css and you will get the result you want:

```
#Navbar h3{
    display:inline-block; //this align them in one line
    background-color: black; //initial background color
    color:white; //text color
}
#Navbar h3:hover{
    background-color:gray; //hover background color
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#NavBar h3 {
    display: inline;
    background: #000;
}

#NavBar h3:hover {
    background: #aaa;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I make it so each background is 50px height and 100 px width, while keeping the text in the center at 12px size?